# getting "Unknown Mailbox" error when sending email using EWS API (C#)

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices, office365api

I'm simply trying to use the Office 365 API to send an email via the "Send()" function, but am getting back ***Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.ServiceResponseException: Mailbox does not exist.***

Here's my exchange service:

```
                        _emailExchangeService =
                        new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1)
                        {
                            Url = new Uri(_settings.ExchangeWebServiceEndpoint),
                            Credentials = new WebCredentials(_settings.AppEmailUserName, _settings.AppEmailPassword),
                            TraceEnabled = true,
                            UseDefaultCredentials = false
                        };
```

And here's the code I'm using to send the email:

```
       public void SendEmail(MemoryStream attachment, string body, string subject, string recipients, string fromMailbox)
    {
        EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(_emailExchangeService);

        message.From = fromMailbox;
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.Text, body);
        message.ToRecipients.Add(recipients);
        message.Attachments.AddFileAttachment("FileName", attachment);
        message.Send();
    }
```

What mailbox am I forgetting to define when sending this, the sent box? I thought the "from" field would define the mailbox for sending items. I'm just not even sure where to do that and my code looks identical to the docs.

Side note: I know the exchange service is set up correctly because if I define an inbox email address and attempt to FindItems(_inbox) on the mailbox, it works.

Comment: I have the same problem! I found the email I was intending to find. I found it but I cannot FORWARD it.  Like you said, everything is in that email (it is the item in FindItems) Just no clue why FORWARD function keeps giving out an error saying "Mailbox does not exist" -- sounds like the service has forgot the Mailbox I have just found my mail from!  Doesn't make sense.